# css method doesn't work with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var slidemenu_width = $('.inverse').css('width');
$('#slide-nav .navbar-toggle').css({'left':slidemenu_width + 'px'});
```

what's wrong with this code? I don't see the css been applied to my selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<div class="inverse" style="width:25px;"></div>
<div class="navbar-toggle"></div>

var slidemenu_width = $('.inverse').css('width');
$('.navbar-toggle').css('left',slidemenu_width); // add css like this
```

Comment: what if I have multiple property like width and color? i have to put object as param of css();

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#slide-nav .navbar-toggle').css({'left':slidemenu_width});
```

Comment: already px is added with the slidemenu_width , so no need to add again in css